# What's wrong with this function to check for a class inside an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, class, iframe

I'm trying to place an overlay on ustream's embeddable player (a countdown...). Evidently I am doing something wrong, as the function below does not yield the expected results. If anyone could have a glance over it, and point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated! [Is this even possible?]

```
<script>
$('#ustream-iframe').load(function() {
    if ( $("#ustream-iframe").contents().find("#PlayerOne").hasClass( "screen-shown" ) ) {
         $("#offair").show();
     }

     else {  
         $("#offair").hide();
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: How about using delegate.

Comment: I've already gotten around the issue with the API – more elegantly, perhaps. As to your comment, I should really have mentioned that my knowledge of Javascript is somewhere between 'pretty bad' and 'non-existent' – so I don't exactly follow, when you say 'use delegate', but if need arises I shall google in this direction. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: reached your goal? If so Im happy to say "you are wellcome". Read (carefully) the delegate API description on the official jquery website.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, for what I'm trying to achieve, the easiest solution was to use the [Ustream embed API](https://github.com/ustream/embedapi) which features the required callback hooks.

Like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var channelLive = function(){
        $('#offair').hide();

    }
    var channelOffline = function(){
        $('#offair').show();

    }
    var viewer = UstreamEmbed('ustream-iframe');
    viewer.addListener('live', channelLive);
    viewer.addListener('offline', channelOffline);



});
</script>
```